# How to redirect URLs to login page?

Tags: java

I have an application which has a login page which comes up with the URL:

http://localhost:8080/Analyze

when the user fills the login page and clicks submit.it goes to a page with the URL:

http://localhost:8080/Analyze/analyze

Now if i copy the url:http://localhost:8080/Analyze/analyze and paste in a new browser window I get

HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

What can I do to redirect back to the login page:

http://localhost:8080/Analyze if I copy paste http://localhost:8080/Analyze/analyze in a new browser window.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't state how you are handling the requests so my answer is necessarily vague.

For that URL you need to write code to handle the HTTP `GET` method and forward the request to the page you want.  If you're in a servlet you'd do something like this:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
      throws ServletException, IOException
{
  String urlStr = "/Analyze";
  RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(url);
  dispatcher.forward(req, resp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're taking POST data from the login page.

Perhaps a solution would be to check for the existence of login data, without any data being passed, you could redirect to localhost:8080/Analyze